# What is the proper way to use transactions in firebase with Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angular7

I normally use AngularFire2 when working with Firebase. But this time i did not, i used the normal Firebase library because when i checked the docs on AngularFire2 for the usage of transaction which i need, i didn't find it.

Using the normal Firebase library i came across this error which says the transaction wasn't committed, but the data still saves to Firebase.
Can anyone please point out the mistake i have made?

Here is my code:

```js
saveSeats(key, numbers){
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    const num = numbers[i].toString();
    const objPath = `${this.basePath}/${key}/${num}`;      
    const busesRef = firebase.database().ref("buses/"+key+"/"+num); 

    busesRef.transaction(function(currentValue) {
      if (currentValue === null) {
        let newRow = JSON.stringify({ number: num, status: "reserved", timestamp: Date.now() });
        busesRef.child("0").set(newRow);
      } else {
        console.log('Value Already Exists');
      }    
    }, function(error, committed, snapshot) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Transaction failed abnormally!', error);
      }else if (!committed) {
        console.log('We aborted the transaction (because number already exists).');
      } else {
        console.log('Number added!');
      }
      console.log("Number: ", snapshot.val());      
    });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `set()` method in your transaction, as presented in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction):

> Note: Modifying data with set() will cancel any pending transactions
>   at that location, so extreme care should be taken if mixing set() and
>   transaction() to update the same data.

You should "pass `transaction()` an update function which is used to transform the current value into a new value."

So the following should normally work:

```
  busesRef.transaction(function(currentValue) {
    if (currentValue === null) {
      let newRow = JSON.stringify({ number: num, status: "reserved", timestamp: Date.now() });
      return newRow;  // <- Here the function returns the new value
    } else {
      console.log('Value Already Exists');
      return; // Will abort the transaction.
    }    
  },
  ....
```

---

Finally, I think that you don't need to stringify your object. Doing the following should work:

```
      let newRow = { number: num, status: "reserved", timestamp: Date.now() };
      return newRow;
```

or, of course, simply

```
      return { number: num, status: "reserved", timestamp: Date.now() };
```

---

**A further consideration:**

I've noticed that you wrap your transactions within a `for` loop, meaning that you will modify the values of different `busesRef` nodes. Shouldn't you do all these modifications within ONE transaction? And not with a set of "atomic" transactions, that each modifies the value of a given `busesRef` node? It depends on your exact use case.

Comment: That clarified a lot for me. Thank you!